# Unable to add CORS support to spring boot data jpa

Tags: angular, spring-boot, spring-boot-jpa

I am getting following exception when trying to access my localhost service.

```
2019-01-22 13:57:27 ERROR o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping.exposeEffectiveLookupPathKey(RepositoryRestHandlerMapping.java:264) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping.lookupHandlerMethod(RepositoryRestHandlerMapping.java:165) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.getHandlerInternal(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:347) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.getHandlerInternal(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:62) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMapping.getHandler(AbstractHandlerMapping.java:401) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.support.DelegatingHandlerMapping$HandlerSelectionResult.from(DelegatingHandlerMapping.java:108) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.support.DelegatingHandlerMapping.getHandler(DelegatingHandlerMapping.java:74) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.getHandler(DispatcherServlet.java:1231) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1014) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:998) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doOptions(FrameworkServlet.java:937) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:669) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:875) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92) ~[spring-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:770) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1415) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_181]
```

My RestConfiguration class is :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class RestConfiguration implements RepositoryRestConfigurer, WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration repositoryRestConfiguration){
        repositoryRestConfiguration.exposeIdsFor(entityManager.getMetamodel().getEntities().stream().map
                (Type::getJavaType).toArray(Class[]::new));
    }

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry){
        registry.addMapping("/**");
    }

}
```

Angular it throwing following error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/getPositions' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
```

while I can load the URL : http://localhost:8080/getPositions fine in the browser and see the output.

My Angular code is

```
getAllPositions(): Observable<Position[]> {
    const httpOptions  = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders(
        {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://localhost:4200',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTION',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': '*'})
    };
    return this.httpClient.get<Position[]>(this.positionUrl, httpOptions)
      .pipe(
        tap(() => this.log('fetching all Positions')),
        catchError(this.handleError('getAllPositions', []))
      );
  }
```

Please help.

Comment: Have you tried simply putting `@CrossOrigin` on the controller you're calling?

Comment: I don't have controller I am extending spring-jpa-repository

Comment: This is NOT a CORS problem at all.
Spring Data-Rest API cannot map the request to a valid controller-method. Your configuration is also weird. Could you insert the entity class you try to load via that request? And also its repository interface.

Answer (score 1):

As of version 3.1.4.RELEASE, it's a bug in `RepositoryRestHandlerMapping`. The issue has been resolved on Github though, so hopefully it'll be in the next release.

Check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54660081/nullpointerexception-when-making-an-options-request-with-access-control-request) if you want for more info.

**UPDATE**
This was fixed in 3.1.5.RELEASE

Answer (score 0):

The issue is server side as CORS is enforced by the server, not the client, so the Angular code doesn't play a part there, and adding CORS headers in Angular won't help.

My assumptions are you're running the **backend** on port **8080**, and the **Angular** code from port **4200**

Maybe try this:

```
getAllPositions(): Observable<Position[]> {
    const httpOptions  = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders(
        {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'})
    };
    return this.httpClient.get<Position[]>(this.positionUrl, httpOptions)
      .pipe(
        tap(() => this.log('fetching all Positions')),
        catchError(this.handleError('getAllPositions', []))
      );
  }
```

And

```
@Override
public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
    registry.addMapping("/getPositions")
        .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
        .allowedMethods("GET")
}
```

You need to configure the backend service on port 8080 to allow requests from port 4200 - even though both are running on localhost, the different ports trigger the CORS policy violation, so you have to explicitly allow that.

**Edit:**
Maybe set the policy to "*" first, and maybe ideally globally until it's working, and then narrow the scope to the specific URL for security.

```
    .allowedOrigins("*")
```

Comment: I don't believe i have /api/** anywhere in the URL. thanks for your help

Comment: tried that as well but did not work. thanks for your help.

Comment: The base problem is that you need to configure the server to allow requests specifically from port 4200, either by setting a global CORS policy, or a route specific one. I would suggest setting a global CORS policy maybe for "*" first until you get it working, then narrow the scope to the specific domain.