# NullPointerException when making an OPTIONS request with Access-Control-Request-Method in Spring-data-rest

Tags: java, spring-boot, cors, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I get the following exception when making an OPTIONS request:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping.exposeEffectiveLookupPathKey(RepositoryRestHandlerMapping.java:264) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping.lookupHandlerMethod(RepositoryRestHandlerMapping.java:165) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.getHandlerInternal(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:368) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.getHandlerInternal(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:65) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMapping.getHandler(AbstractHandlerMapping.java:401) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.support.DelegatingHandlerMapping$HandlerSelectionResult.from(DelegatingHandlerMapping.java:108) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.support.DelegatingHandlerMapping.getHandler(DelegatingHandlerMapping.java:74) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.getHandler(DispatcherServlet.java:1231) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1014) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doOptions(FrameworkServlet.java:944) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:669) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.
```

The request I am making is:

```
curl 'http://localhost:9091/api/authors' -X OPTIONS -H 'Access-Control-Request-Method: GET' -H 'Origin: http://localhost:3000'
```

I'm doing this to mimic a pre-flight request from my front end where I originally noticed the problem.

If I remove the 'Access-Control-Request-Method' header from the request, everything proceeds normally.

I am using SpringBoot version 2.1.1. Here are my dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security')
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    runtimeOnly('com.h2database:h2')
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')

    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest:2.0.3.RELEASE'
}
```

and this is my security config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity(debug=true)
public class SecurityConfig  extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    }
}
```

You can find a demo project here: https://github.com/cekali/spring-problem

I really appreciate any help that anyone can provide, I am stumped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It's a bug** in `RepositoryRestHandlerMapping`'s `exposeEffectiveLookupPathKey` method. Although it has been fixed on Github, the latest version (3.1.4.RELEASE) has not been unfortunately.

**Further information:**
The exception is thrown because the method expects a `RequestMappingInfo` object that encapsulates information from the `@RequestMapping` annotation on the `HandlerMethod`. But for preflight requests, the `HandlerMethod` that is returned and subsequently used (see [`AbstractHandlerMethodMapping`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/handler/AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java#L79)) has no such annotation, so the `RequestMappingInfo` object is `null`. Calling methods on it will of course throw a `NullPointerException`.

This is the fix you'll see on [Github](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-rest/blob/master/spring-data-rest-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/RepositoryRestHandlerMapping.java#L260):

```
private void exposeEffectiveLookupPathKey(HandlerMethod method, HttpServletRequest request, String repositoryBasePath) {

    RequestMappingInfo mappingInfo = getMappingForMethod(method.getMethod(), method.getBeanType());

    if (mappingInfo == null) {
        return;
    }

    ...
}
```

**UPDATE**
This was fixed in 3.1.5.RELEASE

Comment: any thoughts on how I can fix this within my application? My solution at the moment is to downgrade spring-boot to 2.0.5.RELEASE

Answer (score 0):

You can  customize your prefilght requests as follow:

I have user Spring Boot 2.1.3.RELEASE

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.cors().and()       
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/**",).permitAll() //custom logic
        ...................
        .............
    }


    //define the Corsbean and add your cutom headers here
    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
         CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
         configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
         configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
         configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Access-Control-Allow-Headers","Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
                 "Access-Control-Request-Method", "Access-Control-Request-Headers","Origin","Cache-Control",
                 "Content-Type", "Authorization"));
         configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
         configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("*"));
         UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
         source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
         return source;
     }

}
```